# Scripting GPU LED color change

Tags: scripting, gpu, nvidia, api-design

I'm in an attempt to make a conditional based GPU LED color changing script, however this has been more of a challenge then I thought it would be, I was really sure it would be pretty straight forward, however I can't seen to find anything on this GPU feature, so, has anyone heard of an API for such purposes or am I gonna need to deal directly with the hardware(what I've never done before)?
I know this question is a little too unspecific, I apologize for that, however, I really need at least a direction on where to start, as I've never ever ventured this deep into my electric charges conductors(a.k.a. hardware).

Obs: The GPU in question is a Gigabyte GTX 1060 D5 Rev. 2(I also failed in finding any documentation on it… Besides the "Users guide" at least, what is "not really helpful" at best)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They released support recently in the SDK published [here](https://www.gigabyte.com/mb/rgb/sdk). In it they include sample C++ code for calling into `GvLedLib.dll` in `B18.1004.1.zip\Sample\Peripherals\LedDemo`.

I built a .NET wrapper that uses PInvoke to interact with the library to produce a CLI tool. That project can be found on GitHub as [RGB Fusion Tool](https://github.com/tylerszabo/RGB-Fusion-Tool).

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I was looking for. I honestly wasn't expecting to see any answer after so long.

Answer (score 0):

Is there plans to add variable color based on temperature?

I'd really like it if I could have my `1080GTX` (for example) be blue and slowly change to red as it got warmer.

As it is, it seems the most you can do is have the brightness change based on temperature.

[MANISH PATIDAR](https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100007329525369&ref=bookmarks)

Comment: Well, my actual intentions are much sillier, but, I guess that's something I could easily do if I can just figure out how handle the color change. To be honest I hadn't thought this could have an actually useful purpose, so, if this succeeds I may finally have a not-completely-wasteful GitHub project after all...